# ASP.NET ObjectDataSource could not find a non-generic method that has parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, objectdatasource

I am using a FormView control on an ASP.Net page with an ObjectDataSource that is linked to a Business Tier component connected to stored procedures in the SQL Server. I am getting the ObjectDataSource could not be found error and I have made sure that all my components contain the parameters (and that they exist).

[image]

**I can't figure out why it can't find the parameters even though they are there?**

Stored Procedure:

```
UPDATE [Anime_List] SET [Name] = @name, [AnimeImage] = @anime_image, [Synopsis] = @synopsis, [Type] = @type, [Episodes] = @episodes, [Genres] = @genres, [Rating] = @rating WHERE (([AnimeID] = @original_animeID));
```

Business Component:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update)]
public static void UpdateAnimeList(string name, string anime_image, string synopsis, 
    string type, short episodes, string genres, decimal rating, int original_animeID,
    int animeID)
{
    animeList.AnimeListUpdateCommand(name, anime_image, synopsis, type, episodes,
        genres, rating, original_animeID, animeID);
}
```

Database Design:

[image]

Table Adapter Configuration:

[image]

ASP.Net:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="AnimeDataSource" runat="server" DeleteMethod="DeleteAnimeTitle" InsertMethod="InsertAnimeList" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetAllTitles" TypeName="Business.BAnimeList" UpdateMethod="UpdateAnimeList">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_animeID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="anime_image" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="synopsis" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="episodes" Type="Int16" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="genres" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="rating" Type="Decimal" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="anime_image" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="synopsis" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="episodes" Type="Int16" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="genres" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="rating" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_animeID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="animeID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be failing looking for another AnimeImage.

I'd suggest matching the casing (capitalization, don't use under_case) and order of the arguments the error page is asking for.

Something like

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update)]
public static void UpdateAnimeList(string name, string **animeImage**, string synopsis, 
    string type, short episodes, string genres, decimal rating, int original_animeID,
int animeID) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ahaha. That worked. Really strange though, I used underscores as the parameter identifier in my Stored Procedure but the Business method doesn't like it. Thanks!